# Why Am I Getting "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'encode'"?

Tags: python, tweepy, sentiment-analysis

I am running this as I am trying to do a sentiment analysis of tweets I have collected.

```
# Instantiate new SentimentIntensityAnalyzer
sid = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()

# Generate sentiment scores
sentiment_scores = tweets['text_lemmatized'].apply(sid.polarity_scores)
```

But I get this error message. Not sure why.

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

Comment: one of your functions is trying to encode a string. The error returned tells you that instead of a string, it is receiving a list object.

Comment: Ah darn. You are right. I tried passing in a list accidentally. Thanks.